# How to order the last twelve months in a date table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing all dates of the last four years (2018 - 2021) and I would like to have a column with a chronological order based on the last twelve months.
This is what the table currently looks like:

| DATE | YEAR | MONTH | MONTH_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-03 | 2021 | 10 | October |
| 2021-10-02 | 2021 | 10 | October |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021 | 10 | October |
| 2021-09-30 | 2021 | 9 | September |

And now I like to add another column that orders all records based on the last twelve months.
Today is in October 2021 so the last twelve months would be October 2020 - September 2021 and the correct order for each month no matter which year should be:

| MONTH | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| October | 1 |
| November | 2 |
| December | 3 |
| January | 4 |
| February | 5 |
| March | 6 |
| April | 7 |
| May | 8 |
| June | 9 |
| July | 10 |
| August | 11 |
| September | 12 |

Comment: If you used `Row_Number()` to generate values ordered by `Year * 12 + Month` ... . Wrap it in a `case` expression if you want `null` for all earlier (or later) months. Or is the question how to get only the most recent 12 months?

Comment: _I would like to have a column with a chronological order based on the last twelve months_ But time moves forward always and passage of time does not alter the contents of an actual column. Just add a sequential number to your calendar in date order. That number is the same for all the dates within any give month. You can then easily get the last 12 (or next 3 or whatever) based on the value of that sequence for the current date (or for any other date) - no math needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to map the months as you asked for, you need to use `[ORDER] = ((DATEPART(MONTH, DATE) + 2) % 12)+1`

For example,

```
DECLARE @Factor INT = 12 - DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
;With MyCTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 200 D = DATEADD(MONTH,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)), '2000-09-01')
    FROM sys.all_objects
)
-- I am using the above CTE only to create some data for the sample.
-- It represent the data from your table
-- If you can provide DDLD+DML then we can present it with your sample data
--> here we do the map betwen the date and the requested ORDER column
SELECT D, DATEPART(MONTH, D), [ORDER] = ((DATEPART(MONTH, D) + @Factor) % 12)+1
FROM MyCTE
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your example is working perfectly, Ronen.
I was able to include the following line in a view to get the needed result::
´´´
SELECT ((DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) + (SELECT 12 - DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()))) % 12)+1 AS 'ORDER'
´´´
Of course instead of GETDATE(), I am using the column with the datetime.

Once again thank you very much!!